# Quitar duplicados de un arreglo de enteros primitivos con una lista de lamndas

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Hola me podrian ayudar alguien, ya que estoy tratando de quitar duplicados de un arreglo con eneteros primitivos, el problema que tengo es que al convertirlo a una lista para utilizar Streams me manda un error de casteo. LEs agradesco su ayuda. Saludos.

```
public static int[] sinDuplicados( int[] is) {
    List<int[]> listArray = new ArrayList<>();
    listArray=Arrays.asList(is);    

    List<Integer> lista = (List<Integer>) listArray.stream().distinct();

    System.out.println(lista);
    return null;
}
```

El error que me manda es el siguiente.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.stream.DistinctOps$1 cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at arrays.EliminarDuplicados.sinDuplicados(EliminarDuplicados.java:38)
    at arrays.EliminarDuplicados.main(EliminarDuplicados.java:13)

Answer (score 1):

**Código de prueba con la función arreglada:**

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] lista = sinDuplicados(new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 });

    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(lista));
  }

  public static int[] sinDuplicados(int[] is) {
    return Arrays.stream(is).distinct().toArray();
  }
}
```

**Explicación:**

Creamos un stream a partir del array de enteros, usamos la función `distinct` y lo reconvertimos a un array.

No hay necesidad de usar las clases ArrayList, List o Integer para esto.

**Échale un vistazo a este repl.it que he creado con una demo:**

https://repl.it/@HorusGoul/DeepskyblueCoordinatedMapping

---

Si tienes dudas dejame un comentario y te lo respondo cuando pueda :)

Comment: La respuesta funciona, pero no explica al usuario cuál es su problema (que no tiene nada que ver con *streams*). Mejor explicarle qué es lo que falla, y no darle un código para que haga copy & paste. +1 de todas formas.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias aprendi algo nuevo Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema no tiene nada que ver con lo que comentas, o con *streams* (nota: Deberías fijarte en el stacktrace para ver en qué línea te falla, y en el mensaje para ver cuál es el problema para ver por dónde van los tiros. Es un dato MUY importante).

```
List<int[]> listArray = new ArrayList<>();
listArray=Arrays.asList(is); // Por cierto, no crees un objeto que vas a descartar en la línea siguiente.
```

*listArray* lo declaras como una lista, y cada elemento de la lista sera **un int[]**, no un *int*. Y lo que salga del *stream* seguirá siendo un *List<int[]>*, y por eso te falla al hacer el *cast* a *List<Integer>* (que es el mensaje que sale en la excepción).

Obviamente, no puedes crear un *List<int>* por *int* es una primitiva, no una clase. Por eso al hacer *Arrays.asList(is)* te devuelve un *List<int[]>*, pero eso no es lo que quieres. Lo que te da es una lista con un único elemento que es todo el array *is*.

Así que lo más sencillo es tratar el *int[]* como un *stream* directamente.

```
List<Integer> resultado = Arrays.stream(is).distinct().toArray();
```

(Nota: al hacer *Array.stream(int[])* el *stream* acaba siendo un *IntStream*, que es un *stream* de *Integer*, no de *int*).

Si quieres usar tu enfoque inicial, tendrás que meter los números en tu *List<Integer>* "a mano" (con un bucle o con un *stream*) antes de hacer la operación.

```
List<Integer> listArray = new ArrayList<>();
for (int entero : is) {
   listArray.add(entero);
}
// aquí el resto de tu código
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda amigo.